# Weka Class Invalid for Deserialization

Tags: deserialization, cluster-analysis, weka

I trained a SimpleKMeans clusterer in Weka Explorer and saved the model to my computer. Now I want to use it in my Java code to cluster an instance I create but I get the following error when I try to deserialize it:

> java.io.InvalidClassException: weka.core.Instance; weka.core.Instance;
>   class invalid for deserialization     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:288)  at
>   weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(SerializationHelper.java:270)  at
>   Test.main(Test.java:32)

where line 32 of my Test class is

```
Clusterer kmeans_temp = (Clusterer) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("path/to/model/myclusterermodel.model");
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was because I was using two different versions of WEKA to create the model and deserialize the model. I downloaded the source code for the version I used for WEKA explorer and problem solved.